# how to redirect using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, token, window.location

As you can see, I'm using a login form that validates user and password online, generates a token and is supposed to redirect the user to a `pacientes.html` page  once the token exists.

The problem starts  in `renderApp`. It does execute the `window.location.href`, but in order to redirect, I have to manually refresh the page. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
let ruta = 'login'

const renderApp = () =>{
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token) {
        window.location.href = "pacientes.html"

    }
}

window.onload= () => {
    renderApp()
    const loginForm= document.getElementById('login')
    loginForm.onsubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        const cedula = document.getElementById('cedula').value
        const password = document.getElementById('password').value

        fetch('https://janfa.gharsnull.now.sh/api/auth/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({cedula, password})
        }).then( x => x.json())
          .then( respuesta => {
            localStorage.setItem('token' , respuesta.token)
            ruta = 'users'
          })
    }

}
```

Comment: So the url gets changed but page doesnt reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect when you get the response from the HTTP request, then put the code to redirect in the `then` callback.

i.e. replace `ruta = 'users'` with `location.href = "pacientes.html"`.

If you put it in the render function, it will only get executed when the component renders!

Comment: oh god thank you very much. I'm just learning js and this kind of things is somewaht difficult to me